# Creating legend for data-defined colors in table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend

I am using QGIS 3.10.6.

I have imported satellite imagery and geological maps from government servers. The polygon tables have a column with a code for colors. Such that I can color code my map with the exact same colors using the embedded color code. I do it through assigning a string to the simple fill for the polygon in the "single symbol" category. Since I am using a single symbol, it seems that I cannot create a legend for all the different units (color codes).

Is there a way to create a legend for polygon tables with data-defined colors using the "single symbol" symbology?